# Missing elements in getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to get all the links from this site:
https://www.supremecourt.uk/cases/search-results.html?q=affidavit

with the following code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$html = file_get_contents("https://www.supremecourt.uk/cases/search-results.html?q=affidavit");

$docs = new domDocument; 

$docs->loadHTML($html); 


$anchors = $docs->getElementsByTagName('a');

$links = array();

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    echo $links[] = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    echo '<br>';
}
```

but the returned links do not include links from the search results. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Provide the output you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search results on this site are provided by Google CSE via JSONP request and probably (not sure as I never tried to "break" CSE but there is signature in request to Google so this task is not easy for sure) couldn't be obtained from PHP or other ways that don't include the headless browser which can do all JS things (PhantomJS, CasperJS, Selenium).

Comment: Hi, Roman. I run scripts from free hosting, so I don't know if I can use headless browsers. I'll try regex. If you have more suggestions, do write them. Thanks.

Comment: @LukaszB regex can't help you. Look at code (view-source:https://www.supremecourt.uk/cases/search-results.html?q=affidavit) there is no search results.

Comment: @LukaszB Just researched a bit. You can try to request https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1element?v=1.0&q=affidavit&key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1gunmMikTzQqY&cx=000046730316008719618:zmvytun3c8i to get results in JSON format. But be careful because I'm pretty sure that after some requests in short time from same IP Google may start to return CAPTCHA.

Comment: Hi, Roman. Thanks again, you're saving me tons of time. I'll look into the api.